# How to smooth readings from an on-board accelerometer (light blue bean)

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, smoothing

I'm wondering if someone with more Arduino knowledge than me can point me towards the right direction to solve this. I'm trying to smooth out some accelerometer readings. I was following the suggestion to do so over here: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Smoothing

The issue is that I'm using a Light Blue Bean which has an on board accelerometer which calls a struct? And has some form of on-board filtering: https://punchthrough.com/bean/the-arduino-reference/accelerationreading/  | https://punchthrough.com/bean/the-arduino-reference/getacceleration/

I'm not sure how to go about this. Try and smooth each axis (https://punchthrough.com/bean/the-arduino-reference/getaccelerationx/)? work of the arduino digital smooth example? Maybe smoothing is the wrong approach?

Mostly its just giving me some big jumps in readings even when its sitting still. ie: the y-axis will be: 0, 1, -8, 0, 3, etc.. in a sample.

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am less than a novice on this, but this page https://punchthrough.com/bean/the-arduino-reference/getacceleration/
says the conversion for the units to "Gs" is 3.91X10-3.  So, if you multiply the values you are getting by .00391, then you should get the units in Gs.  Your value of -8 above is only -0.03128G. This is a reasonable acceleration for something "sitting still."